# Google Sheets: Enter value from a cell when a value from a different sheet matches that particular value from its row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've searched and cannot find the formula or way to get the result I'm looking for in Google Sheets.

I'm using two sheets: ITEMS, RECIPES:

```
ITEMS has two columns: ITEM_NAME, REF_RECIPE
RECIPES has two columns: RECIPE_NUM, RECIPE_NAME.
```

I would like to have the REF_RECIPE value in ITEMS auto-populate with the RECIPE_NUM value of the RECIPE_NAME from RECIPES if ITEM_NAME in ITEMS is in the RECIPE_NAME column.

Any guidance would be appreciated. I've added screenshots for reference.

As you can see in the ITEMS screenshot, the current formula isn't working:

```
=IF( COUNTIF(RECIPES!A$2:B, C2) > 0, RECIPES!A2:A, "" )
```

The REF_RECIPE values **should be**:

| REF_RECIPE | REF_RECIPE |
| --- | --- |
| water | R0004 |
| boiled egg | R0003 |
| cloth | R0002 |
| paper | R0001 |
| water | R0004 |

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image: ITEMS sheet]
[image: RECIPES sheet]

Comment: vlookup, xlookup, index/match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XLOOKUP()` function.

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,F:F,E:E)
```

To make it dynamic spill array, use `MAP()` function.

```
=MAP(A2:A6,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,F:F,E:E)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, good sir! XLOOKUP is what I needed. I had to do some additional tweaking to my formula, but it all worked out because of your guidance. I ended up using LET with XLOOKUP, which turned out to work as I needed it. Again, thank you.